# C# how to grep a content from a large file

Tags: c#

i'm very familiar with python and now learning C#. please help me out

i have a large file, but in this large file, i only want to grep this content and write it into a separate file.

```
                RxDqLeft RxDqRight RxVLow RxVHigh TxDqLeft TxDqRight TxVLow TxVHigh
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    N1.C0.D0.R0:   -16       16       -23       21      -19     19      -14      14
    N1.C0.D0.R1:   -17       16       -23       21      -20     20      -15      14
    STOP_RMT_N1
```

i have tried so many things. really need help. here's my code that doesn't seem to work

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\users\20609\Desktop\801968_20140606_024500.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("RxDqLeft RxDqRight RxVLow RxVHigh TxDqLeft TxDqRight TxVLow TxVHigh"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    while (!line.Contains("STOP_RMT_N1"))
                    {
                        list.Add(line);
                        continue;
                    }



                }
            }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Out of memory?

Comment: You got endless loop here: `while (!line.Contains("STOP_RMT_N1"))`

Comment: i'm not getting the expected content to displayed in the output

Comment: @user3148235 well your code is wrong. as ShadowWizard pointed out you'll have to add some sort of break condition to your loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take all lines before the line containing `STOP_RMT_N1`, and don't take first line (which contains title), you may do this

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\users\20609\Desktop\801968_20140606_024500.txt")
               .Skip(1)//don't take title, which is probably (?) on first line
               .TakeWhile(m => !m.StartsWith("STOP_RMT_N1"));//or Contains if STOP_RMT_N1 is not at start of line
```

Of course, you may have performance problems with `File.ReadAllLines` if your file is really large. Then a StreamReader may be usefull.

So you can correct your code to

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\users\20609\Desktop\801968_20140606_024500.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("RxDqLeft RxDqRight RxVLow RxVHigh TxDqLeft TxDqRight TxVLow TxVHigh"))
                        continue;//loop to next line

                    if (line.Contains("STOP_RMT_N1")
                        break;//get out of the loop

                    list.Add(line);

                }
            }
```